# How to resize between 3.5" and 4" screens (dynamic constraints in autolayout?)

Tags: xcode, constraints, autolayout, screen-size

I have one view filling the screen with a background image. Other views (text fields) are in exact positions (the background image includes the text field background images). When I change from 3.5" screen to 4", the text fields don't change in the same way that the background resizes. The bg image simply resizes to fill the screen, but the text fields jump out of alignment.

Is there a way to have two sets of constraints, one for each screen size? or is there a way to have views resize proportionally to another view?

EDIT:
[image: 3.5" Screen]

[image: 4" Screen]

Comment: How have you defined the constraints at the moment? In code, or in interface builder? What layout are you aiming for?

Comment: The constraints are in interface builder. When I change to the 4" screen, all the views make some kind of attempt to rearrange themselves, which makes me think it is possible to have them properly resize.

Comment: I guess what I really want is each view to act as if its frame covers the whole screen (lots of invisible space then), and when the screen changes size, the frame is stretched to still cover the whole screen.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your layout with the constraints showing? What you're asking sounds strughtforward but you're probably being defeated by interface builder and it's non obvious UI.

Comment: I added some screen shots. The orange text, along with images and their boxes are all part of a single background image. All uitextfields have a constraint between themselves and the left side of the screen, which is why there is no problem there. Vertically, "username" has a constraint to the top of the screen, "What will you send me" to the bottom, and all others are constrained to each other, going up from "what will you send me", but nothing is connected to "username". What I'm really wanting is to have two sets of constaints without needing a huge/any amount of programming

Comment: (I thought Apple would have thought this over since there is a convenient button to change the screen size and see how it looks in the interface builder).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have two sets of constraints, one for each screen
>   size?

Yes,  by adding constraints programatically and checking [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] to get the screen size.

> or is there a way to have views resize proportionally to another view?

Yes, you could set this up in interface builder.  But it will be hard to manage, I would manage the constraints manually in code since you are using a custom background image the textviews need to position exactly

Answer (score 0):

You're going to struggle to get these things to line up properly with the text view backgrounds being part of the background image.

You should amend your image assets and use the `background` property of `UITextField` to have an actual background image, and remove the boxes from your main background image. The icons could be separate images as well.

Failing that, it would make more sense to have the image stretch underneath the text boxes rather than on top.

Your layout is doing what it should do based on your description, but the image isn't stretching in the right way. In your screenshots, username is always the same distance from the top, and the others are the same distance from the bottom, but that isn't how image stretching works. I don't know how you've set it up but it would make sense to have a single image the size of the 4 inch screen, which has the bottom cut off for 3.5 inch devices, and constrain everything from the top.